# C# Converting a StreamReader string to a Double

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read in each line and determine whether the line contains a specific string `"Donated"` or any double number.

1. If the string `"Donated"` is found, increment a variable by 1.
2. If a double is found, add the value to the variable.

However, I have 1 problem: when I convert the string to a double using `dConverted`, it outputs the numbers as a set of string being added together. For example, if it read 3 lines, each containing the number 1, I would end up with the total of "111" instead of "3".

Here is my code :

```
double dConverted;
string sLine= "";
string dCount = "";
int iSponsors = 0;
string sWords = "Donated";

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("DONATIONS.TXT"))
{
    while (sr.Peek() != -1)
    {
        sLine = sr.ReadLine();      // Read in the Line
        if (sLine.Contains(sWords)) // If Line contains donation text, add another sponsor
        {
            iSponsors++; // Increment sponsor amount
        }
        else // If sLine does not contain Donated
        {
            dConverted = Convert.ToDouble(sLine);
            dCount = dCount + dConverted; // Store the numbers in a variable
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sLine); // Write the line to console
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Total amount sponsored: " + dCount);
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter any key");
Console.ReadKey();
```

The question is; How do I end up with a totalled number instead of multiple strings being added together?

[image: My current output:]

Comment: your variable type for `dCount` is wrong.

Comment: Well of course, it's a string. change `dCount` to a double, and then in the line `Console.WriteLine("Total amount sponsored: " + dCount);` change the code to `Console.WriteLine("Total amount sponsored: " + dCount.ToString());` also, instead of `dCount = dCount + dConverted;` you can do `dCount += dConverted;`

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre No need for the `ToString` in the `Console.WriteLine` because addition with a `string` will automatically call `ToString` on the other value (that's why it's concatenating the values in the current code instead of giving a compilation error).

Comment: @juharr I know that that's a thing, but I thought it was worth mentioning as  the OP might not be fully confident on type usage :D

Comment: Wow, I guess that's what happens when I'm in a rush :/
Thanks for spotting my newb error :)
I have a small amount of experience and reading from a file is new to me.

Thanks all :D